# How to run a cython script through a python file?

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, cython

I have a compiled cython script which i normally run in powershell by typing `py` and then `import main`. But Is there a way to run the script in a python file so i can just run `python run.py` in powershell?

I tried using subprocess but it didn't work and i couldn't figure it out.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.system('py')
subprocess.system('import main')
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer answers your question, if it doesn't work I'll continue trying my best to help you further.

Comment: I included an example below that should work, to verify if it is something just specific to the main file you're trying to import.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to respond, your answer worked, thank you :-]

Comment: No problems, I'm glad it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a `run.py` file or whatever you want to call it. Then add `import main` to the file. Then you run it by typing `python run.py`.

 You should just be able to import it like any other python module, just make sure the files are located in the same directory.
(or look at [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder))

To verify with fib.pyx example from [cython tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html).

first we make the `fib.pyx` file containing the code below.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def fib(n):
    """Print the Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a + b

    print()
```

To verify we cant already use it by making a small `test.py` file.

```
import fib 
fib.fib(2000)
```

running that with `python test.py` will give the error`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fib'`.

So we continue to make a `setup.py` file

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("fib.pyx"),
)
```

Now running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` will build your extension.
Now if you run `python test.py` again it will not give an error and it will output.
`1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597` 
What is the same but now for a file as they did in the tutorial by launching the python interpreter and running

```
>>> import fib
>>> fib.fib(2000)
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597
```

(I also tested this on the pure cython function primes and it works the same, you can just run it from a file if you write it exactly like you would in the interpeter and just run it using `python <fileName>.py`)